# Sirius and Xtext generated Languages - Diagram with cross references

Tags: eclipse-rcp, dsl, xtext, eclipse-sirius

I have a project with 2 different DSL developed with xtext. DSL B uses elements of DSL A. I added Sirius to my Editor and want to show the Elements in a digram. My issue is now, that I have to choose a root model class from DSL B. When I generate the diagram only elements of DSL type B are shown, the referenced elements of type A are not drawn. It seems when I choose one model it only resolved this model and the imported elements of DSL A are not resolved. Is there a way to set maybe the genmodel of DSL B as the root, so all elements of both ecore models can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The question is confusingly-worded but if I understand correctly, you simply need to use the 'Add' tool from the 'Existing Element' section of the palette on the right of your diagram.